# Localizing a JSF 1.2 application with UTF-8 resources

Tags: java, jsf

(WARNING: this is my first java application, coming from .NET, so don't bash me if I write too much garbage)

I'm developing a simple JSF 1.2 web application which should support Russian, Chinese, and other languages outside ISO 8859-1, which is automatically used in `Properties.load()`.

Is there a way to use the Properties loaded from XML files, with `Properties.loadFromXml()`, inside JSF, without writing too much code?

I know there are alternative ways to do so (writing my own loader, escaping the characters...), but I'd really love to find a simple solution, and I don't see it in all the forums I checked.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most widely used approach is to encode your `.properties` files with unicode escape sequences. This can easily be done with the [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) plugin for Eclipse.

The problem is that `ResourceBundle` uses the `Properties(inputStream)` constructor, rather than `Properties(reader)`.

You can use your own `LoadBundle` component instead of `f:loadBundle` to overcome this, but you'll have to:

- extend the original one
- define it as custom component (facelets and/or jsp)
- define a new `ResourceBundle` implementation
- instantiate it, using `new InputStreamReader(classloader.getResourceAsStream(..))`